# Need to Get data for an index for a timeframe using curl or using url

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, elasticsearch-5

I need to Get data for an index for a timeframe using curl or using url.

I was able to get the data using below created url

http://localhost:9200/index_name/_search?size=10&q="* AND severity:major|critical"

but I am not sure where to provide the timeframe for example i only want data from last 15minutes.

Can anyone help me with a way it can be done

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_ranges) by adding `@timestamp:[now-15m TO now]` to your query:

```
http://localhost:9200/index_name/_search?size=10&q="* AND severity:major|critical AND @timestamp:[now-15m TO now]"
```